# 'Erase' Animation for Raphael JS Path

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, raphael

I've created a line animation with RaphaelJS (see jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/7n040zdu/). I'm attempting to create a animation that occurs after this one takes place that is basically an erasing of the initial animation. That is, the line animated out the same way that it is animated in - along the same path, the same duration, the same direction.

I have tried just animating another path on top, but that solution is not preferable. If the initial path overlaps itself, then erasing with another path would reveal that the animation is not 'erasing' but rather being overlapped.

I am having trouble finding something in the [Raphael documentation](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html) that would achieve anything similar to this.

Relevant code below:

#### HTML

```
<body>
<div class='drawings' id="draw0"></div>
</body>
```

#### CSS

```
body {
    background-color: black;
}
```

#### JS

```
var animateLine = function(canvas, colorNumber, strokeWidth, pathString) {
    var line = canvas.path(pathString).attr({
        stroke: colorNumber
    });

    var length = line.getTotalLength();

    $('path[fill*="none"]').animate({
        'to' : 1
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        step: function (pos, fx) {
            var offset = length * fx.pos;
            var subpath = line.getSubpath(0, offset);
            canvas.clear();
            canvas.path(subpath).attr({
                stroke: colorNumber,
                "stroke-dasharray" : "",
                "stroke-width" : strokeWidth
            });
        }
    });
}

var canvas = new Raphael('draw0', 50,50);
var drawPath1 = 'M0.767,0.915 M48.538,20.228L0.767,0.915l3.896,39.312L48.538,20.228L37.663';

animateLine(canvas, '#FFF', '1.5', drawPath1);
```

Comment: why not reverse the path and animate the opacity back to 0?

Comment: @gabereal The animation needs to be 'erased' in the same direction that it was drawn in. Reversing would be the opposite direction, right?

Comment: The currently method feels a bit clunky having to recreate the path each time. You can just animate the stroke-dashoffset attribute 0->pathlength or pathlength->0, then you don't need to recreate any paths each time.

Comment: @Ian Interesting idea, and definitely better than having to recreate the path. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Ian's comment on the original question, I was able to use a single path and then animate the dashoffset of the svg, but it took some further changing in order to get that actually working correctly.

Initially, the SVG path's css is set with the following parameters: `'stroke-dasharray': '9999px'` and `'stroke-dashoffset': '9999px'`. The `stroke-dashoffset` is then animated from 9999px to 9999px minus the length of the path. At the end of the initial animation, the css has to be set once again, this time: `'stroke-dasharray': '999 999'` and `'stroke-dashoffset': '9999px'`. At this point, the `stroke-dashoffset` is animated once again, this time `'stroke-dashoffset': (9999-(length of path)-100)+'px'`.

A jsfiddle showing this is present here: http://jsfiddle.net/tim_m/94ze4ajj/

*Note that in the jsfiddle, I've added more paths with varying opacity and time offsets to give the illusion of a fade at the tips of the line animation.